# Controlling destroy() method

Tags: java, servlets, servletcontextlistener

I'm trying to shutdown my application gracefully.So when the application shutdown is triggered, I need to make the shutdown process wait for configured number of seconds, during this time I would still service few requests.

I have been trying to use wait/sleep in the destroy() method, but the context is already destroyed at this point. My understanding is that destroy() would be called by the container. Is it possible to control the destroy method and delay the start of the shutdown process?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your given approach will not work.**The reason is `destroy()` method.** Every servlet will has their own `destroy()` method.These method is called when the servlet are being unloaded by the container, not when your application is being shutdown.The servlets can be unload when the container will has no use of a servlet.You can have your application running and still your servlet may get unloaded by the container because the container may hav edecided that these servlet are not needed.

**Solution:** What you may need is a ServletContextListener. ServletContext is associated with your whole application,not just with a single servlet. When your applicaion is being loaded,the `contextInitialized()` of ServletContextListener is invoked and when your application is being unloaded, `contextDestroyed()` is invoked.So in `contextDestroyed()`,you can sleep the threa and perform other task.

```
    @WebListener
    public class MyContextListener implements ServletContextListener
    {

        public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event)
        { 
         System.out.println("\n \n \n \n ServletContext is being initialized..... \n \n \n");
            }

        //Perform cleanups like removing DB connection.closing session etc. while closing appliction
        public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event)
        {
            try{
            //Sleep this thread.
            Thread.sleep(10000);
            } catch(Exception ex){ ex.printStackTrace(System.err); }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I do have ServletContextListener in my application and I initially tried this approach, but as it turns out to be contextDestroyed will be called only when the context is about to be shutdown. It's just a notification that the server is going down and by this time the context is already gone and it's not helping..

Comment: @AswinSelvakumar  you misunderstood about ServletContext. There is only and only 1 ServletContext per web application and not your server. The ` contextDestroyed ` is the notification that the application is being unloaded from server, not the server going down.These are 2 different thing. Having said that,i believe i misunderstood your point ` trying to shutdown my application gracefully `. By shutdown,do you mean remove the application from server or is it just like log out from your application or closing the tab in which your application is being used.

Comment: I'm not removing the application, just kinda logging off.. Lets say I have a Http listner in my application, which is listening on the port 8080. Now I'm bringing down my application, with that the listener would be gone as well. And I have to delay the server going down , so that I can server the pending Http request. Hope I explained in detail.. any pointers pls..?! TIA..

Comment: No, sleeping in the [`ServletContextListener::contextDestoyed`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html#contextInitialized-javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent-) method implementation will *not* accomplish the goal of letting the servlet’s do more work. The Servlets have already stopped by then. Per the class doc: *All servlets and filters will have been destroyed before any ServletContextListeners are notified of context destruction.*